# chez les Martin vs chez les Martins

Tags: grammaire, traduction, orthographe, histoire

I want to translate the following sentence into French

> The Martins invite me to their house.

Should I say

> Je suis invité chez les Martin.

Or

> Je suis invité chez les Martins.

?
My tutorial book claims that I should use the former because "les XXXs" is used only to refer to a royal family, like "les Bourbons". But if I use "les Martin" here, it looks somewhat weird. 
Can anyone help me? Best regards!

Comment: Your book (and [Gingko's answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14049/7224)) are correct. For a famous example, _The Simpsons_ are known as _Les Simpson_ in France. I understand it feels weird. Different language, different rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must definitively write “Je suis invité chez les Martin”.
The rule is that proper nouns in French are normally invariable if they don't fall in the exception list, royal family in the case of *Les Bourbons*.

I just made a quick search on Google giving me [that page](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/PROPRE.htm) that describes it more completely in my sense.